# How to properly exclude password property in Odata without loosing POST method

Tags: c#, odata, dto

I'm a bit confused about OData entities structure. Let's take an example of user entity:

```
public class User {
   [Required]
   public string Name;
   [Required]
   public string Surname;
   [Required]
   public string Password;
}
```

And then we adding it to EDM model:

```
var type = builder.AddEntityType(typeof(User));
builder.AddEntitySet("Users", type);
```

Fair enough but... Of course we don't want to expose `Password`. Fortunately there is a lot of way to exclude `password` from exposure. 
One of them is to just set it to `null` on return which in my opinion feels wrong as the field is marked as `Required` and returning `null` just feels wrong.

More common one is to ignore it in EDM model. But there is a problem with that solution, namely `POST` method will no longer receive every data required to create `User`.

```
public ActionResult<User> Post([FromBody] User user)
{
 // user missing password
```

How is user supposed to log-in without specifying password ?
I feel like excluding password from EDM model is not the correct way to do it as well.

Ideal solution would be to use two `DTO's` that would separate `UserInitiator` data structure (that would include password property but not have some other properties like `id`) and `UserInfo` that will contain all 'safe to read' data. Unfortunately OData doesn't seems to allow such a separation.

So, how should i handle `password` property in correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add user creation/login as a separate action, that way it can have a custom parameter type. You can read about OData actions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions). For example, the edm for a user registration action might look something like:

```
var action = builder.EntityType<User>().Action("Register");
action.Parameter<UserWithPwdDto>("user");
```

Where `User` is the entity type of the controller which doesn't include the password property, and `UserWithPwdDto` has the password property and is only used by actions that require that property.

Also I hope the user class you show in your question is not used as your database model, you should **never** save passwords as plain-text in your database.